# Could someone with a good IE JavaScript debugger help me out?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Can you please tell me what snippet of code is failing in IE8 on this page:

http://www.gaiagps.com

I am virtualizing IE on my Mac, and I have no debugger.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: if you're virtualizing IE, it's still running on windows. That means it has a debugger. F12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

( I don't have IE 8 ) but it seems obvious... how about the unenclosed start tags on your script elements?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript/jquery.easing.1.3.js"</script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascript/jqgalscroll.js"</script>
```

Comment: You still didn't fix the first one ( production ) that is.

Comment: Please be thorough and validate all the html after you do fix that and if it still doesn't work.

Comment: If after you fix the first broken script start tag it still breaks, try commenting out entire script snippets locally if you can.

Answer (score 1):

by the way, you can debug with the developer tools on IE8

OR

you can get Firebug Lite and install on your pages to do cross browser debugging.

http://getfirebug.com/lite.html